# How to transpose some columns in row in power query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am currently looking for a way to transpose some of my columns into rows. I have a table in this form:

[image]

And I would like to get something in this shape:

[image]

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You can do this without power query simply by copying the cells, then "insert contents" and select the "transpose" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, click select the first three columns, then right click unpivot other columns, then file close and load